# Original text, Java-run decryption and Android-run decryption are all (slightly) different

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm attempting to run a simple encryption/decryption Android app and testing it in Java as well. I've searched and haven't found an answer that's related to my problem.

Essentially, the encrypting and decrypting is working for the most part, except the text after decryption in Java and Android are both slightly different than the original text that became encrypted. For example, `how's it going?` is decrypted as `howsitgoing=` in Java and `howsitgoAAAA` in Android.

Here's the Java code:

```
KeyStore ks = null;
try {
    ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType()); 
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("./raw/./akeystore");
    ks.load(is, "a".toCharArray());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate("akeypaircer");
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey)cert.getPublicKey();
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

byte[] decodedString = Base64.decodeBase64("how's it going?".getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte [] cipher = c.doFinal(decodedString);

RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey)ks.getKey("akeypair","a".toCharArray());
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

byte [] decrypted_cipher = c.doFinal(cipher);
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(decrypted_cipher);

System.out.println(new String(encodedBytes, "UTF-8"));
```

I'm *assuming* it has to do with character encoding but I know nothing about that...

I'm also guessing that maybe the difference between Java and Android exists because I have to use two different keystore types (BKS for Android and JKS for Java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is patently wrong:

```
Base64.decodeBase64("how's it going?".getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

`"how's it going?"` is not a base 64 string, and you cannot base 64 decode it. The idea is to base 64 encode the ciphertext if you require a ciphertext represented as character string. For the plaintext, you need to convert from a character string to bytes. But you already did that by *encoding* it as UTF-8.

In short:

- you can create text from bytes by performing [encoding](/questions/tagged/encoding) (e.g. base 64, base 32, hexadecimal encoding)
- you can create bytes from text by performing [character-encoding](/questions/tagged/character-encoding) (e.g. ASCII, ISO 8859-1 "latin", UTF-8 and UTF-16BE or LE)

Comment: Yep, that was it. Told you I knew nothing about character encoding. (Encoding was the problem on my previous question too).

Comment: @EmbattledSwag I guess that about 50% of the encryption problems here have to do with encoding/decoding instead of encryption/decryption. So you are not alone there. That said, I guess that about 80% - if not higher - also has some kind of security issue, such as forgetting to add integrity and authenticity to a ciphertext. It may also have issues like using RSA in ECB mode instead of hybrid encryption with a symmetric AES key (hint, hint).